# Can't fix warning messages after react native upgrade

Tags: reactjs, react-native, warnings

After upgrading to react native 0.25.1 I get yellow warning messages that don't go away after I make all the changes indicated in the release notes. How can you track down the where the errors are occurring? I've searched and found nothing other than the code called for on this page: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases

Comment: What warning are you getting? It's going to be very difficult to provide any kind of help without knowing which message you're seeing and preferably the code that causes it.

Comment: Oh, yes, sorry ... the ones that arise from changes indicated on that release page: `ReactNative.Component is deprecated. Use React.Component from the "react" package instead` ... `ReactNative.createClass is deprecated. Use React.createClass from the "react" package instead` ...... and two others in the same vein.

Comment: So... how are you importing the `Component` you're extending? Using ES6 you'd do `import { Component } from 'react'` but without knowing what your code looks like it will, again, be hard to answer this question.

Comment: This is what I'm using: `import React, {Component, PropTypes} from "react";

import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  ScrollView,
  TouchableHighlight
} from 'react-native';`   I've changed every component to this style and still I get errors, though the warnings don't say where from.

Comment: I haven't worked much with react-native but I've added that tag hoping someone who has willl see this. You should edit your question to add the code that generates the warning, preferably enough code that someone else can work out what's wrong. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more on how to detail a question about this.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The problem is that the warning gives me no idea of what code is generating the warning. I've eliminated all of the deprecated code that I had.

Comment: All I am saying is that if it's difficult for you, who has access to the source code, to tell what the warning is about it will be no easier for someone else who can't see it to tell what's wrong. I'm trying to help but it's not easy for anyone to diagnose code they can't see. If you are able to reproduce the warning with a small code sample you will be much more likely to get an answer.

Comment: You probably have some dependencies that still use the deprecated imports. Try setting a breakpoint in node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ReactNative/ReactNative.js at line 41. That's where the warning is triggered and you will have a stacktrace to help you find the offending code. Of course if it's in 3rd party code you should get the author to fix it or do a PR.